# How to send mail from flex mobile application 4.6 without popping up any mail client. I am going to deploy this app on Ios and Android.

Tags: mobile, flex4.6, flash-builder4.5

I am new to flex 4.6 and want to send mail with all the fields of email aumatically generated. i want to do this all on a single click.

Answer (score 0):

See [the Employee Directory example project](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/employee-directory-android-flex.html) for Android, Blackberry and iOS by Christophe Coenraets:

```
protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
{
    var action:Object = list.selectedItem;
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case "tel":
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("tel:"+action.details));
            break;

        case "sms":
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:"+action.details));
            break;

        case "mailto":
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:"+action.details));
            break;
    }                   
}
```

For subject and other fields try appending `?subject=` and `&body=` after the mail address eventually combined [with escape function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#escape%28%29).

[image]